# Nested function calls always together

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have several functions which save various global variables my program uses. They are always called together and so I created a function to call them as follows:

```
def save_reflector(rf):
    with open('reflector.txt.',mode='w') as f:
        for num in rf:
            f.write(str(num)+'\n')

def save_rotors(r1,r2,r3,rpos1,rpos2,rpos3):
    with open('rotors.txt.',mode='w') as f:
        f.write(str(rpos1)+'\n')
        for num in r1:
            f.write(str(num)+'\n')

        f.write(str(rpos2)+'\n')
        for num in r2:
            f.write(str(num)+'\n')

        f.write(str(rpos3)+'\n')
        for num in r3:
            f.write(str(num)+'\n')

def save_wiring(wr):
    with open('wiring.txt.',mode='w') as f:
        for num in wr:
            f.write(str(num)+'\n')

def save_machine(r1,r2,r3,rpos1,rpos2,rpos3,wr,rf,v = None):#use v for verbose option
    if v is not None:
        print('Saving rotors...')
        save_rotors(r1,r2,r3,rpos1,rpos2,rpos3)
        print('Saving wiring...')
        save_wiring(wr)
        print('Saving reflector')
        save_reflector(rf)
        print('Machine Successfully saved')
    else:
        save_rotors(r1,r2,r3,rpos1,rpos2,rpos3)
        save_wiring(wr)
        save_reflector(rf)
```

So, I always call of these functions together, never separately. Which is why it occurred to me to just have on function to call all of them. But that requires me to pass variables twice from outer to inner function (which might be less efficient?) and isn't exactly necessary when I could just type them all. However, `save_machine()` seems nicer and more pythonic when used in my main loop.

I'm not sure which is more pythonic or efficient and so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: `if` condition in `save_machine` function looks useless

Comment: Not the question, but I was just testing out some options to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate point of this clustering is to serve the readability and maintainability of the code.  Since your business process mandates that these three functions be called in sequence as an easily named process step `save machine`, it makes perfect sense to wrap that in a function.  This is not only more Pythonic, it makes the same sense in almost any application, regardless of language.

This removes clutter from your calling program, and reduces the chance of later development making an error in handling this step.  You've reduced about ten lines of coding to only the one -- the function call -- in your calling program.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with forwarding inputs. Being able to group related statements together is the entire point of having methods in the first place.

Generally when writing code like this I start with the following mindset. 2 occurrences may be a coincidence, but three is a pattern. i.e. if you're writing the same piece of code more than two times where the only thing that changes is the input variables, then it's time to make a function.

Lets start with the code `for num in rf: ...`. I see this everywhere. Let's move that logic to its own method:

```
def write_r(f, r):
    for num in r:
        f.write(str(num)+'\n')

def save_reflector(rf):
    with open('reflector.txt.',mode='w') as f:
        write_r(f, rf)

def save_wiring(rf):
    with open('wiring.txt.',mode='w') as f:
        write_r(f, rf)
```

Now with a little bit of work, `save_rotors` could be made to handle `n` pairs of inputs

```
def save_rotors(r_list, rpos_list):
    with open('rotors.txt.',mode='w') as f:
        with r, rpos in zip(r_list, rpos_list)
            f.write(str(rpos)+'\n')
            write_r(f, r)
```

Your main method is still much the same:

```
def save_machine(r1,r2,r3,rpos1,rpos2,rpos3,wr,rf,v = None):
    ...
    save_rotors([r1,r2,r3],[rpos1,rpos2,rpos3])
    save_wiring(wr)
    save_reflector(rf)
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer! I accepted the other answer because it was a more direct answer to this question for others who may be interested. But I will be implementing this!